# How to add Thai language to CiviCRM in WordPress?

Tags: localisation

I'm using WordPress v4.9.5 and install CiviCRM v4.7.31
I want to activate 'Thai' language to CiviCRM, but there is no option to include this one into system.
I try to check at Administrator > Localization > Language, Currency, Locations
There is only one available which is "English (United States)"

I also try to contribute to translate project at https://www.transifex.com/civicrm/civicrm/translate/#th_TH but there is no progress yet, it's about 5%

I download l10n from https://download.civicrm.org/civicrm-4.7.31-l10n.tar.gz but don't know how to install these folders to CiviCRM (there are multiple folders of l10n, and sql folder which does not have Thai files)

Could anyone help me?

Comment: It sounds like you've already discovered the Thai translation is only around 5% complete. It would be great if you can help translate at the transifex.com link you've posted.

Comment: Yes, of course... I've been contributed to translate these words from English to Thai language in the meantime, however the question is, how do I apply new updated translation to CiviCRM in WordPress?

Answer (score 2):

Since it's below 20% they aren't included in the download. You can use the instructions in the [Administrator Guide wiki](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/i18n+Administrator%27s+Guide%3A+Using+CiviCRM+in+your+own+language#i18nAdministrator'sGuide:UsingCiviCRMinyourownlanguage-Updatingyourtranslationfiles) to get the files into CiviCRM. There is also more information at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/translation/wikis/home

Answer (score -1):

Would it be possible if I use some script of Google Translate or another plugins to WordPress for making translation directly on CiviCRM?

I try to use this one >> Translate WordPress with GTranslate https://wordpress.org/plugins/gtranslate/ but it works on frontend pages, but it does not work on backend system.

Comment: This sounds like a separate question so should be posted as a separate question, but in CiviCRM you can try Administer -> Customize data and screens -> Word replacements, but that feature isn't really intended for full translation.

Comment: Yes, it could be separate question, however actually it's still in my intention to translate CiviCRM from English to Thai language.